# PHP String (not an array of numbers) in SQL Not in operator

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use a php string as a *not in* argument *within a sql statement.* The php string I wanted to use looks like the following:

```
$excludedValues = "test,these,origin"
```

I would like to use that string as an argument in the following sql:

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT u.name FROM user u WHERE u.name NOT IN(:names)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array('names' => $excludedValues));

    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The excludedValues are being ignored.. what am I doing wrong here?

Information: It is not an array, and even with using an array and implode, I couldn't get it to work.

Regards.

Comment: updated information within the question. It is a string, and not an array of numbers. I already tried the same by exploding the string into a string array, and then using implode, but couldn't get it to work.. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: you should use trim() after exploding such a wrongly composed string

Comment: Already did that. The problem when using strings is, that the parameter of "not in" is expected to like like the following: .. NOT IN("test","these","origin").. and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The sooner you realize this is a *most exact duplicate*, the sooner you will have your problem solved. check the link I posted

Comment: I'm trying with "call_user_func_array" now as described in the other post. sry, i was kind of confused right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you were kind of confused when tagged your post with mysqli while actually using PDO. So you don't need call_user_func_array at all.

Comment: Oh sheesh. I just wanted to Tag mysql..ha

Comment: Working when using "?" to bind parameters, thanks